# How do I SUM two cast columns and group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to produce a balance query.  I have the following query below:

1. I would like to sum FunctAmt1 and FunctAmt2.  (I had to use the cast function, as the data is varchar, and I needed to convert to number) **SOLVED**
2. I would then like to group by account number, so that I get one record per account.  But when I group it errors at me.  (With the below query I still see two multiple records per account, and not the total balance.

Any suggestions / support is greatly appreciated.  thank you for help in solving point 1.

```
SELECT
[Company_number],
SC.[DESCRIPTION],
[account_number],
[account_description],
CAST([ACTL_FUNC_AMT] AS DEC(12,2)) + CAST([ACTL_BGNNG_MO_FUNC_AMT] AS      DEC(12,2)) AS FunctAmt
FROM [balances]
JOIN [company_details] sc
   ON [company_number] = [company_number]
WHERE [company_number] = '132' AND NOT CAST([ACTL_FUNC_AMT] AS DEC(12,2)) = 0 AND      NOT CAST([ACTL_BGNNG_MO_FUNC_AMT] AS DEC(12,2)) = 0
GROUP BY [company_number],
SC.[DESCRIPTION],
[account_number],
[account_description],
   [ACTL_FUNC_AMT],
   [ACTL_BGNNG_MO_FUNC_AMT]
```

ORDER BY [account_number]

Comment: Looks like sqlserver?

Comment: Could you post the error please.

Comment: `SUM()` is for adding values from multiple rows with `GROUP BY`. If you just want to add two columns, just write `column1 + column2`

Comment: `cast(...) + cast(...)`

Comment: Show the query with `GROUP BY` that gets the error.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what you've tried it's a little tough to say, but my guess is maybe you only added a `group by account_number`? You'll need to add the rest of the columns that aren't part of the aggregate. Is this what you're after?

```
SELECT
    [Company_Number],
    T2.[Company Description],
    [Account_Number],
    [Account_description],
    SUM(CAST([ACTL_FUNC_AMT] AS DEC(12,2)) + CAST([ACTL_BGNNG_MO_FUNC_AMT] AS DEC(12,2))) AS FunctAmt
FROM [general_ledger_data] 
JOIN [company_details] t2
    ON [Company_Number] = [Company_Number1]
WHERE [Company_Number] = 'Comp1'
GROUP BY [Company_Number],
    T2.[Company Description],
    [Account_Number],
    [Account_description]
ORDER BY [Account_Number]
```

Comment: Hello Everyone - the suggestions worked and sovled question 1.  I updated the code.  The only issue I have now is my group by is not working... it works and doesn't give me an error.... but I still see multiple records for one account... I just want to see the total balance per account... (effectively creating a trial balance) thank you :)

Comment: Without sample data it's hard to say what's happening. Can you edit your post to include some data? If you remove company number, company description, and account description from the select and group by what do you get?